# Why a string starting with 'cat....' outputs with a different color in Programiz?

Tags: python, colors, output, cat

I can't figure out why when I print a string starting with 'cat..' (like category, cathedral, catch, ...) in the [Programiz Online Python Compiler](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) it appears in green (or gray and italic in dark mode) instead of black (or white in dark mode).

[image: Exemple]

```
print('cathedral')
print('car')
```

Anyone knows? Is there a joke or something I'm missing?

Tried in a different Programiz Online Compiler, like the C one, and it also happens there!

Comment: Not here. And since it is online, can't be a version thing. The only reasons I can think of is that you have either an extension or some local settings. I've you tried with all extension disabled?

Comment: Yes, tried with 3 different computers with different browsers.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I've read too fast. You meant in the output area, when running program that prints thing. I was expecting to see syntax coloring doing this in the code area. But yes, I see it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, since this is client side, the easy way to know is to inspect javascript code (even if it is minified, that part is quite readable. Just search for `cat` in it)

And, indeed, there is explicit code to tread as "batch comment" some regexp in the output area.
Including `^cat.*`. And many others.

For example

```py
print("/tmp/bla")
print(">") # but with nothing else
print("node bla.js")
print("mono ouchNoPlease.cs")
print("javac monoWasNotThatBadAfterAll.java")
```

Why cat is among a series of regexp apparently for compiler commands, I don't know. And why gcc or many other classical compilers aren't, neither. Nor why, since cat is, no other unix/bash/batch command are.

But whatever the reason, it is no accident, and there are explicit code to color anything starting with `cat`

Edit: my (other) mistake, `gcc` is in the list. It was just before `cat`, and since I read this code by researching `cat`...

Here is the extract of the javascript code of programmiz:

```js
[{token:["comment.line.colons.dosbatch"],regex:"(?:^|\\b)gcc($|\\s.*$)",caseInsensitive:!0},
 {token:["comment.line.colons.dosbatch"],regex:"^(/tmp).*$",caseInsensitive:!0},
 {token:["comment.line.colons.dosbatch"],regex:/^g\+\+.*$/,caseInsensitive:!0},
 {token:["comment.line.colons.dosbatch"],regex:/^cat.*$/,caseInsensitive:!0},
 {token:["comment.line.colons.dosbatch"],regex:/^>/},
 {token:["comment.line.colons.dosbatch"],regex:"^(javac).*$",caseInsensitive:!0},
 {token:["comment.line.colons.dosbatch"],regex:"^(csc|mono).*$",caseInsensitive:!0},
 {token:["comment.line.colons.dosbatch"],regex:"^(node).*$",caseInsensitive:!0}]
```

Wider context is that this is inserted into Ace (since programmiz use Ace editor) syntax coloring rules.

So, the only outliers in the list are `>` and `/tmp/` for the non command strings. And for commands, well, it is precisely `cat`.

Maybe there is a language compiler/interpreter outside unix world that is called `cat` I am not aware of. Or maybe `cat` is considered to be a very raw interpreter (after all, it does execute a very simple language that prints all instructions :D)

Answer (score 1):

After testing out various strings, I think the terminal emulator is lazy and is treating the word "cat" as the bash command `cat`. The color will only change if the first 3 letters are exactly "cat"; if anything separates them, or there is a space before them, nothing happens. Similarly, it does not at all care what comes after it. It is also interesting that by first three letters, it is looking at the terminal output and not the python string. for instance `print("\ncat")` still produces the different color, just on a different line.

I attempted to test calling `cat` through python to see if I was right, but the compiler refuses to load `os` or `subprocess`. I can confirm it happens on my end though.

Comment: I thought about it as well, and tried other unix commands (cd, pwd, ls, ...), but non of them behaved the same way.

Comment: But it doesn't happen with no other bash command. Btw, strictly speaking, `cat` is not a bash command. It is just a unix program. From bash point of view, it is just a program, like `firefox` or `xterm`. Not just playing smartass here. But that diminish the probability of a bash syntax coloring. And no other classical unix command (`ls`, `awk`, `mkdir`, ...) nor bash keywords (`for`, `while`, ...) does the same thing.